# Trying to make a date slicer which includes both date and time

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table of many datetime datapointname value triplets from process probe sensors.

I want to have a slicer which I can use to pick from time1 on day 1 to time2 on day 2
So my approach has been to have three slicers   [Time Start] [Date Slicer] [Time End].   I have the data table and two time tables in 30 minute intervals so I have been able to create measures and display cards to show on the report the start and stop datetime combo.
I try to combine all this into a new table using DAX which filters the data table using the measures that I have but have not had any success.
Does anyone how how to set up a slicer or set of slicers so I can filter my report (for example), from 2022-Jun-15 at 4:30 PM to 2022-Jun-18 at 10:00 AM?

I am just learning about DAX.  I have spent a few hours at this with no sucess.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That's probably not a good idea from a modelling perspective. Data modelling best practice suggests that your Date (where 1 row = 1 day) and Time (where 1 row = 1 second or 1 minute, as necessary) dimension tables should be separate.

I would therefore recommend you setup your model in such a way that you have these two dimensions as two separate tables. You should then just be able to have two slicers - one from each table - to do what you need.

Note: this of course means that your fact tables will need to have separate columns (one for the date and one for the time) to join to your Date and Time dimension tables.